# Theorem 4.20 in Baby Rudin: How is this map not uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

Let $E$ be a bounded, non-compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $x_0$ be a limit point of $E$ such that $x_0 \not\in E$, and let $f \colon E \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by 
$$f(x) \colon= \frac{1}{x-x_0} \ \ \forall x \in E.$$ 
Then how to explicitly and rigorously show that the map $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $E$? Of course, $f$ is continuous on all of $E$!

I've not been able to fully convince myself as to the soundness of the argument adduced by Rudin.

My effort:

For any points $x$, $y \in E$, we have 
$$\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert = \frac{\vert x - y \vert}{\vert x-x_0 \vert \cdot \vert y-x_0\vert}.$$ 
Let $\delta > 0$ be arbitrary. Take $x$, $y \in E$ such that $\vert x - x_0 \vert < \min(1, \frac{\delta}{4})$, $\vert y - x_0 \vert < \min(1, \frac{\delta}{4})$. Then we have 
$$\frac{1}{\vert x-x_0\vert } > 1,$$ 
$$\frac{1}{\vert y-x_0\vert } > 1,$$ 
$$\vert x - y \vert \leq \vert x - x_0 \vert + \vert x_0 - y \vert < \frac{\delta}{4} + \frac{\delta}{4} = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta.$$ 
Howvever, 
$$\vert f(x) -f(y) \vert = \frac{\vert x - y \vert}{\vert x-x_0 \vert \cdot \vert y-x_0\vert} > \frac{\vert x -y \vert}{1} \geq \vert x-x_0 \vert - \vert y-x_0\vert.$$

What next? How to proceed from here?

Or, is there some other way of stipulating the bounds on the distances of  $x$ and $y$ from $x_0$?

We have to find some real number $\epsilon > 0$ such that there are points, say, $x_\epsilon$, $y_\epsilon \in E$ for which 
$$\vert x_\epsilon - y_\epsilon \vert < \delta,$$
but 
$$\left\vert f(x_\epsilon) - f(y_\epsilon) \right\vert \not< \epsilon.$$

Comment: It blows up. Isn't that enough to convince yourself?

Comment: Reduce to a very concrete problem. Consider $1/x$ on an interval around the origin, but with a hole at the origin. Can you show that's not uniformly continuous? (It's the same problem)

Comment: If is U.C. it's sublinear, you function go to infinity, so isn't sublinear therefore isn't U.C.

Comment: @davide If by underlinear you mean Lipschitz, then no.

Comment: Can anyone please complete my argument? I'd prefer a more rigorous argument than the comments above. What if $x_0 < x$ for all $x \in E$? Or if $x_0 > x$ for all $x \in E$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$You've got what appears to be a good proof. Here's a sketch of a rigorous alternative (possibly more conceptual) approach:

**Lemma 1:** If $f:E \to \Reals$ is uniformly continuous, and if $(x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $E$, then $\bigl(f(x_{n})\bigr)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

**Lemma 2:** If $f:E \to \Reals$ is uniformly continuous, then $|f|:E \to \Reals$ is uniformly continuous. (Generally, a composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.)

(The proof of each involves little more than walking through the definitions.)

Now, since $x_{0}$ is a limit point of $E$ but is not an element of $E$, for each positive integer $n$ there exists an $x_{n}$ in $E$ such that $0 < |x_{n} - x_{0}| < 1/n$. The sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$  is (almost obviously) Cauchy, but
$$
|f|(x_{n}) = \frac{1}{|x_{n} - x_{0}|} > n\quad\text{for each $n$.}
$$
Consequently, $\bigl(|f|(x_{n})\bigr)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is not Cauchy. Contrapositively, Lemma 1 implies $|f|$ is not uniformly continuous, and Lemma 2 implies $f$ itself is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: thank you so much for such a wonderful answer!! And, please accept my apologies for my belated acknowledgement.

Comment: +1 for a nice, clean proof. An alternative suggestion: we can avoid using Lemma 2 entirely. Using the fact that Cauchy sequences are bounded, we can show that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is not Cauchy.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally come up with a proof. Here it is:

Let's choose a real number $\epsilon$ such that $0 < \epsilon < 1$. Let $\delta > 0$ be any real number. Now we choose points $x$, $y \in E$ as follows:

Choose $x \in E$ such that $0 < \vert x - x_0 \vert < \min(1, \frac{\delta}{3})$, and choose $y \in E$ such that $0 < \vert y-x_0 \vert < \frac{1}{2} \vert x - x_0 \vert = \vert \frac{x+x_0}{2} - x_0 \vert$. Such points $x$ and $y$ do exist in $E$ since $x_0$ is a limit point of $E$ (but not an element of $E$).

Then we find that 
$$\vert x - y \vert \leq \vert x - x_0 \vert + \vert y - x_0 \vert \leq \frac{3}{2} \vert x - x_0 \vert < \frac{3}{2} \frac{\delta}{3} = \frac{\delta}{2} < \delta. $$ 
However, 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert &=& \left\vert \frac{1}{x-x_0} -  \frac{1}{y-x_0} \right\vert \\ 
&>& \left\vert \frac{1}{x-x_0} - \frac{1}{\frac{x+x_0}{2} - x_0 } \right\vert \text{ [Is this step correct?] } \\
&=& \frac{1}{\vert x - x_0 \vert} \\
&>& 1 \\ 
&>& \epsilon. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Is this proof correct?

Comment: @Brian can you please do me a favor? Can you please check my proof and make any corrections necessary?

Comment: @Brian M. Scott could you please take time going through my proof and then let me know if it's correct? And if not, then can you please also supply the proof that is the correct one?

Comment: This looks close, but not quite OK. At the inequality before "[correct?]", however, the reverse triangle inequality gives$$\left|\frac{1}{x - x_{0}} - \frac{1}{y - y_{0}}\right| \geq \left|\frac{1}{|x - x_{0}|} - \frac{1}{|y - y_{0}|}\right| = \frac{1}{|y - y_{0}|} - \frac{1}{|x - x_{0}|} > \frac{1}{|x - x_{0}|} \dots.$$